# access jade element using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have an input tag of type text. I want to access the value of input tag whenever user enter and push it to the json.

my jade file looks like,

extends layout

```
block content
  h1 todos
  #task
  <input type="text" id="task" name="task"/>
  #todos
    for todo in todos
      include todo
```

I am writing access code using express,

```
    app.get('/', function(req,res){
        todos.push(new todo(req.bodyParser.task)) 
        res.render('index',{todos:todos});
});
```

I am beginner to javascript,node and jade as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use form to submit your data to server:

```
block content
  h1 todos
  form(action="/todos", method="post", id="taskform")
    input(type="text", name="task")
  #todos
    for todo in todos
      include todo
```

In node, now you can access `task` using `req.body.task`:

```
app.post('/todos', function(req,res){
   todos.push(new todo(req.body.task)) 
   res.render('index',{todos:todos});
});
```